# What does the community think about a Facebook page?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I have (finally) gotten on Facebook, and have a thought. I wouldn't mind hosting a 'Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange' Facebook page, to feature highlight questions and answers from the site. Now I don't really know anyone else on Facebook, but this seems like it could be a low effort/time investment that would possibly boost site traffic. ([Here](https://www.pinterest.com/stackexchange/gardening/) is a good featuring style from pinterest) Thoughts?

Comment: Hi J.!  I'm wondering why you haven't previously had a Facebook account. Obviously it's you own business, I'm just curious! :)

Comment: @Sue I'd never really thought about it! I don't really have any friends on it either haha

Comment: Ooops, I meant to get both my comments in place, should've known you'd be quick on the draw :). Didn't want you to think there's anything personal, I just wanted to go on record as saying I hope we don't do this. I have a number of reasons, but haven't formed them into a cohesive answer, so I'm leaving it as a quick comment which I'll delete later once I have an answer in place! Thanks!

Comment: Ok @Sue! Ha in no way would I take things personally... Thank you for the feedback, lookin forward to the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I think the idea of a Facebook page is excellent.  It's irrelevant that it's based upon likes or oil or a Presidential Primary.

From my perspective a Facebook page helps to gain attention for the site.  It allows for interesting gardening questions and answers to be posted on the page and highlighted in order to gain attention and get more views.

I large part of SEO (search engine optimization) for Google is social media.  Right or wrong that's how their weighting works.  If we can get more traffic here because of Facebook AND there are members who would be willing to post a couple of times per day.  It can be an excellent source of more questions as well as more users answering questions.  If a few people find this site and become regulars, that's fantastic too.

Before anyone knocks this idea they should consider that only 14 users have voted this month!

That's terrible but it's more than before.

In order to retain users they must be rewarded for asking questions and answering them.

Facebook  +1

More Voting  +10,000

Comment: I agree about more voting... Anyone wanna beat me to 10k?

Answer (score 3):

FB is based on Friends & Likes. While it *may* be possible to generate *some* traffic, I don't think a FB page would get much notice unless you want to pay for it.

FB is about sharing cute animal/baby pictures, funny/strange videos and funny/political memes. I don't think a Gardening & Landscaping page would be a good fit.

(if you decide to, let me know, I have a few friends I could point to the page)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Hmm... I wonder why almost 800k folks would be following the [**Vegetable Gardening**](https://www.facebook.com/gardeningchannel/?ref=br_rs) facebook page then.

Comment: It has taken them 7 years to get to that number, and you don't know how much (if any) they paid to promote their page. They also have a website that directs to FB.  I'm not saying it can't be done, just don't expect too much.